# Dropdown Check List with "traditional" style?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, combobox, styles

I need a combobox of checkboxes. I found this: http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list and it looks like exactly what I need. But I really don't like it's style (appearance) and it doesn't fit the rest of my page.

Is there any way to have this control with "traditional" style - the same style normal `<select>` and `<input type="checkbox">` have?

If not - is there any other custom control available that does the same but has the "normal" style? Or is there any simple (and short) way to create one by myself?

Comment: You could use CSS to style it the way you want or create your own...

Comment: [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is pretty awesome

Comment: @DavidBélanger I'm not very fluent with CSS - how would I style it to look as desired (normal)?

Comment: There's no such thing as "normal" when it comes to styles - every browser renders them slightly differently. What do you want it to look like? Really you should learn CSS so that you can control the visual presentation of your code.

Comment: @Revent I've said precisely - the same, as default combobox/checkbox.